# how can i remove request from ASINetworkQueue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, asihttprequest

this is the code i use to cancel the download.

```
    NSArray *queueArray =  [downloadQueue operations];
    for (ASIHTTPRequest *request in queueArray) {
        NSString *objid = [request.userInfo objectForKey:Column_objectid];
        if ([objid isEqualToString:audioToDelete.objectId]) {
            [request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
            [request removeTemporaryDownloadFile];
            ...}}
```

but after i call
      [request clearDelegatesAndCancel]

downloadQueue.operations or downloadQueue.requestsCount is still the same count (downloadQueue is my ASINetworkQueue)

how can i remove it from the queue ?
or how can i get the correct operation count of my downloadQueue?

Comment: despite the queue count being same, is the request actually being processed or not after this `clearDelegatesAndCancel` call ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSArray *queueArray =  [downloadQueue operations];
for (ASIHTTPRequest *request in queueArray) {
    NSString *objid = [request.userInfo objectForKey:Column_objectid];
    if ([objid isEqualToString:audioToDelete.objectId]) {
        [request cancel];
    }
 }
```